# How do I make the minimal listen to its IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm testing out minimal API in C# for a small home project. I have this small (!!!!) server code :-):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/test", async () =>
{
    return 1;
});

app.Run();
```

Locally this works just fine. I can open a browser on localhost/test and get 1 in my browser window.

However, I put it on my server running on 192.168.1.91 and now I get connection timeout.

The server application outputs:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

So its bound to localhost, should it not be bound to 0.0.0.0 or * or anything else? localhost is only for that machine?

Comment: localhost is the loopback address. See https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#working-with-ports). Easiest one would be to just pass desired url to `WebApplication.Run`
method:

```cs
app.Run("http://+:5000"); //listen on all interfaces
```

Also I recommend investigating the hosting options:

- [When to use Kestrel with a reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-up-a-reverse-proxy)